# assembly determine input logic

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

Can anyone help me how I can start with my program in assembly language? My task is to write a program that will ask a user for an input (just a single letter, number, or special character)  and the program will determine whether the user's input is a letter, number, or special character. any thoughts? Please help! Not asking for the exact code here as I want to learn how to do it. Im planning to figure it out step by step but any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your target platform: Windows, POSIX, OSX or what?  What is your target architecture: x86, ia64, AMDx64, ARM, SPARC, MIPS or what?  Assemblers are different under different platforms and architectures.

Comment: im on a windows x86, also I am doing this w/ a TASM. Sorry for forgetting to include that sir.

Answer (score 0):

ASSuming your user input is in `al`...

```
cmp al, 'A'
jb not_upper
cmp al, 'Z'
ja not_upper
; arrange to print "uppercase" or "alpha" or "letter"
not_upper:
cmp al, 'a'
jb not_lower
cmp al, 'z'
ja not_lower
; arrange to print "lowercase" or whatever
not_lower:
cmp al, '0'
; etc...
```

A faster way to do it is to create a lookup table and use the input as an index into it - eliminates all the conditional jumps. Probably better to do it the naive way for your first program...

Comment: how about the numbers? and the special characters? can you include it too? :))